# Magento Product Data Transfer from 1.5 to 1.7

Tags: php, database, magento, magento-1.5, magento-1.7

I have made website in Magento 1.7, my old website was in Magento 1.5. Now I want to import all my product data from Magento 1.5 to Magento 1.7

Comment: Is your database structure the same?

Comment: hai +1 for this similar problem

Comment: @relentless db structure is not same for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not deleted the old magento site, you need to downloaded the products csv file by going to Magento Admin > System > Import/Export > Export

and then in your new Magento 1.7 installation, you can import the products csv file by going to Admin > System > Import/Export >Import

Hope this will help you.